# Retrieve clientPID using RpcServerInqCallAttributes

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, rpc

I need to retrieve the client process id in RPC callback which is using ncalrpc protocol. MSDN suggests to use RpcServerInqCallAttributes with RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2  structure. The document says the process id is returned as a handle

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378501(v=vs.85).aspx

I couldn't get that. Is it pointing to a DWORD which has the process id or Is it a process handle where I can get the PID using GetProcessId API?

Also in both cases, who closes the handle or delete the memory allocated for DWORD?

Comment: this is exactly `PID` as is. you can cast it to `DWORD`. really in windows `PID` is handle. look for example [`CLIENT_ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx) or say [`PsLookupProcessByProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551920(v=vs.85).aspx) and many etc. this is only win32 layer convert `HANDLE PID` to `DWORD`

Answer (score 1):

the `ClientPID` is process ID of the calling client as is.

> Is it pointing to a DWORD ?

no

> Is it a process handle ?

no

> I can get the PID using GetProcessId API?

no. this is pid value itself. you can do type cast for use in `OpenProcess` call - `(ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)RpcCallAttributes.ClientPID`

> who closes the handle or delete the memory allocated for DWORD?

it must not be closed (this handle never need be closed) or deallocated (this is not a pointer)

the process and thread id - is really handles in special handle table ([`PspCidTable`.](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=3&a=7&p=6)) it natively represent as handles. native (ntdll) api and kernel mode api always use process and thread id as handles. look for [`CLIENT_ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx)

```
typedef struct _CLIENT_ID {
   HANDLE UniqueProcess;
   HANDLE UniqueThread;
 } CLIENT_ID;
```

this active used in different native api, for example [`ZwOpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567022(v=vs.85).aspx)
all kernel mode api use it as handle, for example - [`PsLookupProcessByProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551920(v=vs.85).aspx)

simply win32 layer truncating `HANDLE UniqueProcess;` to `DWORD UniqueProcess`

so if you want use `ClientPID` from `RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2` structure in win32 call `OpenProcess` - you need simply cast it to `DWORD`. for example:

```
RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2_W RpcCallAttributes = {
    RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_VERSION, RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PID
};
if (RPC_S_OK == RpcServerInqCallAttributes(0, &RpcCallAttributes))
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 
        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)RpcCallAttributes.ClientPID);
}
```

if use native api - type cast not need. for example

```
RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2_W RpcCallAttributes = {
    RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_VERSION, RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PID
};
if (RPC_S_OK == RpcServerInqCallAttributes(0, &RpcCallAttributes))
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };
    CLIENT_ID cid = { RpcCallAttributes.ClientPID };
    ZwOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &zoa, &cid );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given how MSDN goes out of its way several times to say that it's a PID and that the value can be re-used after the client process terminates I would say it being defined as a HANDLE is just wrong, that it is in fact a PID value. That being the case it doesn't need to be deallocated, just let the entire RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES_V2 structure go out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rpcasync/ns-rpcasync-tagrpc_call_attributes_v2_a

> ClientPID
>
> Handle that contains the process ID of the calling client. This field
>   is only supported for the ncalrpc protocol sequence, and is populated
>   only when RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PID is specified in the Flags parameter.

I found this working as PID, not HANDLE. That is:

```
HANDLE hproc = (HANDLE)ClientPID.ClientPID;
NtQueryProcessInformation ( hproc ...)
```

fails, but

```
cpid = (DWORD)(DWORD_PTR)ClientPID.ClientPID;
hcproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, cpid);
```

succeeds.

So MSDN is right: it is represented as a HANDLE, but it needs to be casted to a DWORD PID to be used in subsequent calls.