# How RpcServerInqCallAttributes knows what ClientPID to retrieve

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, rpc

I am reading about the function `RpcServerInqCallAttributes` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcasync/nf-rpcasync-rpcserverinqcallattributesw)).

I saw a program (`vmcompute.exe`) that calls this function like that (based on reversing):

```
RPC_CALL_ATTRIBUTES CallAttributes;  

memset(&CallAttributes, 0, sizeof(CallAttributes));
CallAttributes.Version = 3;
CallAttributes.Flags = RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PID;
Status = RpcServerInqCallAttributes(0, &ClientContextAttributes);
```

It retrieves the PID of `dockerd` but how it knows what PID to retrieve?
It just used the `RPC_QUERY_CLIENT_PID` to query the PID, but based on what? It didn't specify the name of the process.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248007/retrieve-clientpid-using-rpcserverinqcallattributes) answer but it didn't explain how it knows what process PID to retrieve.

Comment: What do you mean by "how it knows what PID to retrieve"? The process id (so the ClientPID struct member) is the id of the client process that initiated the RPC call, RpcServerInqCallAttributes is usually called in RPC server routine.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. This part of a RPC session. In my case, probably `dockerd` call a function in `vmcompute.exe` (which is the RPC server), and then `vmcompute` called `RpcServerInqCallAttributes` to identify the calling process (`dockerd`). But what happens if there are multiple clients that contact the RPC server, how would it know what process ID to retrieve?

Comment: The client is unambiguous if RpcServerInqCallAttributes is called inside the RPC server routine thread, otherwise you must pass the client binding handle as 1st parameter.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Both `RpcServerInqCallAttributes` and its lower-level counterpart `I_RpcBindingInqLocalClientPID` have `RPC_BINDING_HANDLE Binding` as their first parameter:

```
RPC_STATUS RpcServerInqCallAttributes(
  [in]      RPC_BINDING_HANDLE ClientBinding,
  [in, out] void               *RpcCallAttributes
);

RPC_STATUS I_RpcBindingInqLocalClientPID(
  [in, optional] RPC_BINDING_HANDLE Binding,
  [out]          unsigned long      *Pid
);
```

Local RPC requests are usually sent over ALPC, where each message delivered contains both the data payload and LPC/ALPC protocol header, described by [`PORT_MESSAGE` structure](http://www.zezula.net/en/prog/lpc.html). This header has `ClientId` field, which has both senders PID and TID.
Upon receiving an ALPC request the RPC runtime inside the server process saves these values in the `RPC_BINDING_HANDLE` object, where they can be retrieved from.

Passing a NULL handle to `RpcServerInqCallAttributes/I_RpcBindingInqLocalClientPID` means *use the current thread's active binding*, in which case these APIs take the `RPC_BINDING_HANDLE` pointer from the current thread's TEB, IIRC via `ReservedForNtRpc` field.